# How can i add Sample Track of My Songs Releated Items

Tags: magento-1.9, sample

I need to Assign Sample track of my Songs Related Items, In every products i need to set up sample track.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create Downloadable Product from Magento Backend

2) You will get a tab saying something like **"Downloadable infrmation"**

3) By click on the above tab there will be an option  **"Sample"** and **"Link"**

4) Uploaded Audio in **Sample** section will be used for "Sample Audio Track"

5) Uploaded Audio in **Link** section will be used for **"Download"** by your customer who purchased the particular track

Let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: user only hear the sample track , not able to download.

Comment: Yes, Exactly it will behave like this. User will hear only sample track while downloadable link will be accessible when user purchase that track

Comment: add to cart not shown, and out of stock notification,

Comment: show me backend screenshot

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0i14k

Comment: Check inventory tab

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0i1uf

Comment: any options for this

Comment: Upload Link section. You have not uploaded anything there.

Comment: how can i add audio sample track after import the albums.

Comment: Not working.....

Answer (score 1):

You need to create downloadable product

Follow [tutorial](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/downloadable-products) to  for how to create downloadable product

Comment: I need to add sample track, not download the products options.